# Select Dropdown Option that contains spacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, html-table

So I've been trying to create a dynamic table for the better part of the day. I created two dropdown options which would display different table results depending on what's been selected and had got it working, however I realized a bug. I can only put one word as the dropdown selections. Any option with more than one word will break.

Here's my code below for html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Dynamic Tables</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/showhide.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>HTML Table</h2>
<!-- Drop Down Begin -->
<div id="benefits" style="display: inline-block;">
Benefits
</div>

<div id="skyecc" style="display: inline-block;">
    SKYECC
    </div>


<div id="option1" style="display: inline-block;">
    <select class="selectOption">
    <option>Analytics1</option>
    <option>Translation1</option>
    <option>Poll1</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="option2" style="display: inline-block;">
    <select class="selectOption2">
    <option>Analytics2</option>
    <option>Translation2</option>
    <option>Poll2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<!-- Drop Down End -->

<br><br>



<!-- Table and Drop Down Results Start -->




<div id="changingArea" style="display: inline-block;">

    <div id="Analytics1" class="desc">
        <table style="float: left;">
            <tr>
            <td>Analytics P1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Analytics P2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Analytics P3</td>
            </tr>
          </table>



    </div>

    <div id="Translation1" class="desc">
        <table style="float: left;">
            <tr>
            <td>Translation P1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Translation P2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Translation P3</td>
            </tr>
          </table>

    </div>
    <div id="Poll1" class="desc">
        <table style="float: left;">
            <tr>
            <td>Poll P1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Poll P2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Poll P3</td>
            </tr>
          </table>

    </div>
</div>


<div id="changingArea2" style="display: inline-block;">
    <div id="Analytics2" class="desc2">
        <table style="float: left;">
            <tr>
            <td>Analytics T1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Analytics T2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Analytics T3</td>
            </tr>
          </table>



    </div>
    <div id="Translation2" class="desc2">
        <table style="float: left;">
            <tr>
            <td>Translation2 T1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Translation2 T2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Translation2 T3</td>
            </tr>
          </table>

    </div>
    <div id="Poll2" class="desc2">
        <table style="float: left;">
            <tr>
            <td>Poll2 T1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Poll2 T2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Poll2 T3</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Table and Drop Down Results End -->
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my code for css:

```
h2 {
    text-align: center;
}


.desc {display: none;}
```

Heres my js:

```
$(function(){
    $('.selectOption').change(function(){
      var selected = $(this).find(':selected').text();
      //alert(selected);
      $(".desc").hide();
       $('#' + selected).show();
    }).change()
});


$(function(){
    $('.selectOption2').change(function(){
      var selected = $(this).find(':selected').text();
      //alert(selected);
      $(".desc2").hide();
       $('#' + selected).show();
    }).change()
});
```

As i'm a complete noob when it comes to js, any help, suggestions, or insights would be much appreciated.

Thanks again in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you can't have spaces in ID. If your option is `two words` then this line

```
$('#' + selected).show();
```

is selecting for `#two words` - tag `words` within the element with ID `two`.

Usually things like this are done by using a concatenated values for the IDs as well as the option values, while leaving the option text readable.

Make your select like this

```
<select class="selectOption">
    <option value="analytics1">Analytics 1</option>
    <option value="translation1">Translation 1</option>
    <option value="poll1">Poll 1</option>
</select>
```

And you can retrieve the selected value with a simple `$(this).val()` instead of finding the selected option and retrieving text or the value attribute from it.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I did what you said it worked like a charm!